# Arabic numbers are getting reversed in android textview with bidirectional text/numbers

Tags: java, android, bidi

I've been trying to display arabic text with arabic numbers in text view. But the problem is the numbers in text appear in reverse order.

```
((TranslationViewHolder)holder).text.setText("وَاِذَا لَقُوا الَّذِيْنَ اٰمَنُوْا قَالُوْ٘ا اٰمَنَّاﵗ وَاِذَا خَلَوْا اِلٰي شَيٰطِيْنِهِمْﶈ قَالُوْ٘ا اِنَّا مَعَكُمْﶈ اِنَّمَا نَحْنُ مُسْتَهْزِءُوْنَ ١٤ ");
```

Here the string has a number at the end, but this number or any other number gets reversed so number '١٤' become '٤١'.

I have already tried to use Bidi as below

```
String mixedLanguageText = elements[position].getAr(); // mixed-language text

mixedLanguageText = BidiFormatter.getInstance(new Locale("ar")).unicodeWrap(mixedLanguageText, TextDirectionHeuristics.RTL);
((TranslationViewHolder)holder).text.setText(mixedLanguageText);
((TranslationViewHolder)holder).text.setTypeface(typeface);
```

But it has no impact on the output.

I have also tried to setup text direction like below

```
mixedLanguageText = BidiFormatter.getInstance(new Locale("ar")).unicodeWrap(mixedLanguageText, TextDirectionHeuristics.ANYRTL_LTR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said you tried BidiFormatter, I had the same problem with mixed language 'Hebrew/English' and this is how I solved it:

```
//        msg = "506, cvv או תעודת שהות שגויים";

    if(BidiFormatter.getInstance().isRtlContext()){
                Locale rtlLocale = Locale.getDefault(); // RTL locale
                msg = BidiFormatter.getInstance(rtlLocale).unicodeWrap(msg, TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.ANYRTL_LTR);
    }


Snackbar.make(mDrawerLayout,msg,length).show();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I can see a clear difference between the reference string and the hebrew one. The numeric digits are in english in hebrew whereas those are in same arabic dialect in case of my string..So probably Bidi is just continuing with those numbers are RTL rather than treating them as LTR numbers